# Foreach to add Specific Products to an Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I had a previous problem which I have somewhat overcome. However this has resulted in a new problem which when fixed it should be working as intended.

I have created an `array` of **Orders** from a csv file and have managed to extract the data from the **Orders (Products, Address etc.)** and be printed together (Which was originally first problem). For example the csv file contains **2 Orders** which prints them all together such as:

```
Order: Order1
Recipient: Timmy
Address: 123 Street
Products:
Table (Quantity: 1)
Cup (Quantity 4)

Order: Order2
Recipient: Billy
Address: 456 Street
Products:
Chair (Quantity 5)
```

The new problem is now this data needs to go back into multiple `arrays` because of the API which is being used. I have this nearly working apart from the products, which is currently adding products from the previous order. Using the above example, the `array` would be the following:

```
//Order1
array(2)
{
    [0]=> array(7)
    {
        ["Product"]=> string(13) "Table"
        ["Quantity"]=> float(1)
    } 

    [1]=> array(7)
    {
        ["Product"]=> string(13) "Cup"
        ["Quantity"]=> float(4)
    }
}

//Order2
array(3)
{
    [0]=> array(7)
    {
        ["Product"]=> string(13) "Table"
        ["Quantity"]=> float(1)
    } 

    [1]=> array(7)
    {
        ["Product"]=> string(13) "Cup"
        ["Quantity"]=> float(4)
    }

[2]=> array(7)
    {
        ["Product"]=> string(13) "Chair"
        ["Quantity"]=> float(5)
    }
}
```

As shown above, the products from the previous order is duplicated onto the second order. The other order details are working as intended and being inserted as separate records into the database (Order Number, Address etc.). I'm unsure where I am going wrong, but this is the part of the code for the products `array`:

```
    foreach ($Order[$OrderNumber][$RecipientName][$Address1] as $key => $value)
    {   
        $APIOrderItem[] = array('Product' => $key,
                                'Quantity' => $value);
    }

$Items = array('APIOrderItem' => $APIOrderItem);
```

If previous code is required, I'll happily edit this post.

Comment: you want remove duplicate from this $APIOrderItem[]  is it ?

Comment: @jothi That is the actual part which sends data to the database and where it is adding products from the previous Order.

Comment: @jothi So yes, that would be removing the duplicates within $APIOrderItem[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
check_key_value_exists($key,$value)
{
foreach($APIOrderItem as $row)
{


  if($key==$row['Product'] && $value==$row['Quantity'])
    {

       return true;

    }


}

return false;
 }


$i=1;
 foreach ($Order[$OrderNumber][$RecipientName][$Address1] as $key => $value)
{   

   if($i==1)
   {

    $val=false;
   }
   else
   {

      $val = check_key_value_exists($key,$value);

     }


   if($val===false)
   {
      //new  $key and $value insert here 

    $APIOrderItem[] = array('Product' => $key,
                            'Quantity' => $value);


   }
   else
   {

        //$key and $value alreday exists in the $APIOrderItem array so dont need to insert again 


   }

   $i++;
}

 $Items = array('APIOrderItem' => $APIOrderItem);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just a few questions regarding this.

(1) Shouldn't check_key_value_exists($key,$value) have function at the begining of it? I am having an error if function is not included.
(2) If I have this with a function at the begining (And include $APIOrderItem in the brackets), the products are still duplicating.

Thank you however for helping me out! I really appriciate it.

Comment: I have manage to adapt the code and got it to work! Most of the code is the same apart from I added `unset($APIOrderItem);` within `if($i==1)`